# beautifulsoup installation in pyCharm with two versions of python installed

Tags: python, pycharm

I use PyCharm to write Python, at first I configurated PyCharm with Python 2.7.12, and I installed the Beautiful Soup package under the 2.7.12 environment.

However, I now have installed python 3.5.2 in PyCharm and I want to use Beautiful Soup in PyCharm with 3.5.2, but I can't import bs4 because the interpreter cant find the Beautiful Soup package which is in 2.7.12 package folder.

So I tried to `pip install bs4` in 3.5.2 console, but it tells me that the pkg has already been installed in 2.7.12 folder. So how can I import Beautiful Soup in 3.5.2 now in PyCharm?

[image]

Comment: Try changing the interpreter in the project settings to 3.52: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/project-interpreter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure to install your package for the right version of python, you can use pip as a module :

```
python3.5 -m pip install [package]
```

So for bs4 :

```
python3.5 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, be sure to mark it as correct answer by checking the mark below the vote buttons!